# LibreOffice Impress: what is the little orange asterisk icon in the slides list?

Tags: libreoffice

This is Libreoffice Impress 6.4

[image]

As you can see, on the left of slide 24, there is a small icon that comprises both the "white stripes" image and the white arrow pointer.

What is the icon and why is it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cited from [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/155913/impress-whats-the-meaning-of-that-little-star-with-little-mouse-pointer/),

> the small orange asterisk you are seeing means that there is an object with an active animation on the current slide.

Hope this helps!